# C# как изменять объекты не перезаписывая файл целиком

Tags: c#, json

В моей файле около 10к объектов. Эти объекты и должен постоянно удалять и редактировать. Как, используя Newtonsoft можно редактировать, удалять и добавлять элементы не перезаписывая весь файл, а лишь ту часть, что была изменена?

Comment: Никак. Вы можете прочитать всё, изменить как надо, потом записать всё обратно полностью перезаписав файл. Для всего остального есть базы данных.

Comment: Ваше приложение переросло "файлики на диске", надо переходить на базы данных. Не, ну либо продолжайте читать целиком - писать целиком. Файл json не выровнять по блокам фиксированного размера -- так что с этим форматом никак. Можете изобрести свой собственный формат, но как по мне -- проще сразу в сторону БД смотреть.